# Mormon belief in Jesus Christ

Tags: lds, book-of-mormon

Does the Mormon Church teach that Jesus is God?  Hopefully this isn't too simple of a question.

Comment: Depending on your perspective this may be a "Yes, and"... Question.  That they believe he is divine is simple, but how that divinity is expressed is quite different. You may want to ask about the nature of Jesus' divinity within the Trinity.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. I will continue to do research on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://mormon.org/faq/belief-in-jesus-christ:

> Jesus Christ is the literal Son of God. His birth, life, death, and
>   resurrection fulfilled the many prophecies contained in the scriptures
>   concerning the coming of a Savior. He was the Creator, He is our
>   Savior, and He will be our Judge (see Isaiah 9:6, 53:3-7; Psalms
>   22:16-18).

I hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: This is a good start, but it misses actually answering the question. The full LDS belief is much more complicated than this, and includes the teaching that Jesus is a created being, something implied in "literal son of God" but less forthright than just saying "no, He's God's literal son".